# How to extract the original formula (fixed-effects and random-effects) from an lmerMod object?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

Suppose we have postulated the following linear mixed model (LMM), which we generically call `fit`.

```
library(lme4)

fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
```

Suppose that we are also interested in extracting the original formula (i.e. both the fixed-effects and random-effects part) from `fit`, which we would like to pass to a second LMM termed `fit2`. Obviously, passing `terms(fit)` to the `formula` argument of `lmer()` does not work.

```
> fit2 <- lmer(terms(fit), data = sleepstudy)
Error: No random effects terms specified in formula
```

**Question**

Is there a way to extract both fixed-effects and random-effects part from `fit`, which can then be passed to `lmer()`?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the original formula from `fit`, _i.e._ `Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)` ?

Comment: @neilfws yes, that's what I mean!

Comment: `fit@call$formula` will do it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is standard for packages like `lme4` to implement `formula` methods whose sole purpose is to extract formula(e) from model objects, so that you don't have to think too much about object internals.

In `lme4`, there is a `formula` method for class `"merMod"`, namely `lme4:::formula.merMod`. There is no method for class `"lmerMod"`, but since `"lmerMod"` is a direct subclass of `"merMod"`—you can check with `showClass("lmerMod")`—the method for `"merMod"` is called whenever you do `formula(<lmerMod>)`.

Hence:

```r
formula(fit)
## Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)
formula(fit, fixed.only = TRUE)
## Reaction ~ Days
formula(fit, random.only = TRUE)
## Reaction ~ (1 | Subject)
## <environment: 0x11b3944e0>
```

(The last call returns a formula whose environment is not what it should be. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/654) on GitHub.)

`lme4` implements a number of extraction methods for class `"merMod"`. For example, there is also a `model.matrix` method that you can use to extract fixed and random effect model matrices. Most of these methods are documented in `` ?lme4::`merMod-class` ``, so you can use that a reference in the future.

For a complete list of available methods, just look at

```r
methods(class = "merMod")
methods(class = "lmerMod")
```

after loading `lme4`.